# SSIS error when running in SQL Server but not in Visual Studio

Tags: ssis

I am getting the following error in a Data Flow task when I run a certain SSIS package in SQL Server, but the package runs fine in Visual Studio.  Has anyone had an experience like this?

Source: Data Flow Task XML Source [748]   Description: System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.

Comment: Does the resource require some sort of authorization that you running the package in VS has but cannot be determined/is not authorized from the account that is running the SSIS package on the server?

Comment: billinkc,  It doesnt. This package worked before.   Now that I recall, the only difference is another developer worked on it and then passed it back to me for deployment to SQL server.  I have since tried saving it in 2 different versions of VS and then deploying it with no luck.

Comment: ahhhhh. So it's quite possible the package got upgraded to a newer version of SSIS. Or if there were saved credentials in the package they have been smoked.